# Select Tree Structure from two tables

Tags: sql, tree

let us assume I have Table A

```
| PK | Name |
-------------
| 1  | AA   |
| 2  | BB   | 
| 3  | CC   |
```

and table B

```
| PK | FK | Value |
-------------------
| 1  | 1  | i     |
| 2  | 1  | j     |
| 3  | 2  | x     |
| 4  | 2  | y     |
| 5  | 3  | l     |
| 6  | 3  | k     |
```

how can I select the below result

```
| PK | Name |
-------------
| 1  | AA   |
| 1  | i    |
| 2  | j    |
| 2  | BB   |
| 3  | x    |
| 4  | y    |
| 3  | CC   |
| 3  | l    |
| 4  | k    |
```

List parents and under each parent list its children

Many Thanks for help

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Very interesting table design. I believe it's just a matter of unioning your data and then ordering your results how you want them. If it's only a single level child-parent relationship, this should work just fine.

```
If Object_Id('tempdb..#TableA') Is Not Null Drop Table #TableA;
If Object_Id('tempdb..#TableB') Is Not Null Drop Table #TableB;

Select * Into #TableA
From  (Values (1,'AA'),(2,'BB'),(3,'CC')) As a(PK,[Name])
Select * Into #TableB
From  (Values (1,1,'i'),(2,1,'j'),(3,2,'x'),(4,2,'y'),(5,3,'l'),(6,3,'k')) As a(PK,FK,[Value])

;With Cte
As
(
Select PK,[Name],PK As OrderID,0 As LevelID /*Used to ensure parents are put above children*/
From #TableA
Union All
Select PK,[Value],FK,1
From #TableB
)

Select [PK], [Name]
From Cte
Order By OrderID,LevelID
```

**Results:**

```
PK | Name
1  | AA
1  | i
2  | j
2  | BB
3  | x
4  | y
3  | CC
5  | l
6  | k
```

*Note: My last two rows(l and k) are a bit different than results. I assumed you it was typo when you put 3 and 4 as the id's rather than 5 and 6*